# systemd and non-existent *.service files: Are they generic?

Tags: debian, systemd, sysvinit, runlevel

`systemd` units are stored in `/lib/systemd/system` such as:

```
rsync.service
avahi-daemon.socket
bluetooth.service
cups.service
```

When you use the following command:

```
systemctl enable name
```

Replace name with the name of the service unit you want to enable (for example, `apache2`). This command reads the `[Install]` section of the selected service unit and creates appropriate symbolic links to the `/lib/systemd/system/name.service` file in the `/etc/systemd/system/` directory and its subdirectories.

**But** some packages don't have `*.service` files in `/lib/systemd/system`. Examples are `mysql` and `apache2`. Using `systemctl` to enable them works fine:

```
# systemctl enable apache2
Synchronizing state for apache2.service with sysvinit using update-rc.d...
Executing /usr/sbin/update-rc.d apache2 defaults
Executing /usr/sbin/update-rc.d apache2 enable
```

Or

```
# systemctl enable mysql
Synchronizing state for mysql.service with sysvinit using update-rc.d...
Executing /usr/sbin/update-rc.d mysql defaults
Executing /usr/sbin/update-rc.d mysql enable
```

I don't get any result when looking for files related to these services:

```
# find /etc/systemd/system/ -iname "*apache2*"
# find /etc/systemd/system/ -iname "*mysql*"
```

How does systemd find out apache2 or mysql is to be enabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Synchronizing state for apache2.service with sysvinit using update-rc.d...

And there's your answer, right there.  systemd doesn't have service units for these dæmons.  But there are System 5 `rc` scripts in `/etc/init.d/` for them.  So it is processing those scripts, indirectly via `update-rc.d` which is reading their LSB headers, to enable/disable the dæmons.